# How to have a character shirtless?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I know that it could be possible since I've found Trevor shirtless while switching character. But when in the wardrobe there's no option to have a shirtless character or to remove t-shirt.

How can I make my character shirtless?

Answer (score 2):

Scroll all the way to the bottom of shirts list and you'll find it.

Here's a video showing how:

Answer (score -1):

You have to beat the game then there'll be a option to be shirtless under tops